# Data hazards in hardware platforms

Tags: cpu-architecture, hardware-design

I have got a list of 2 types of hazards:

```
1a. EX/MEM.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRs
1b. EX/MEM.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRt

2a. MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRs
2b. MEM/WB.RegisterRd = ID/EX.RegisterRt
```

I am not able to understand the intuition behind these 2 rules which can help me know the technical terms and also explains me the concept? Any explanations are welcome :)

Comment: In most 3-operand ISAs (e.g. MIPS documentation like http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html uses this convention), `rd` is the destination register, and Rs, Rt are source registers.  e.g. `add rd, rs, rt`.  (rs and rt might be second and third, or source and third, IDK).

Answer (score 0):

In most 3-operand ISAs (e.g. MIPS documentation like http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html uses this convention), `rd` is the destination register, and Rs, Rt are source registers.  e.g. `add rd, rs, rt`.  (rs and rt might be second and third, or source and third, IDK).

If you're reading a register (in ID) which was recently written (the instruction writing it hasn't reached the write-back stage), that's a RAW read-after-write true dependency.

Out-of-order exec also introduces the possibility of write-after-write and write-after-read anti-dependency hazards.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards.  But in a scalar in-order pipeline, only true dependencies are a concern, I think.  At least if all instructions have fixed 1-cycle latency, so excluding funky stuff like MIPS `mult` or `div` that write the hi:lo pair.